# How to prove maximality of path connected components

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Source: A *First Course in Topology*,Conover

**4.5 Lemma**

A subset A of topographical space X is path connected iff given x$\in A$ any other of A can be joined to xby a path in A

**Proposition to be proved**

Let X be a topological space and let x$\in $X.Let $P_x$ be the path component of X that contains *x*. If y is any point of $P_x$ and z$\in X$ can be joined by a path in X then z$\in P_x$

From Wikipedia path components are an equivalence relation,but this fact isn’t
noted in my text. So I guess  I
can’t assume it.Also the concept of path connected neighborhood isn’t noticed

**My work.**

Fix x$\in P_x$ There exists a path p from x to y and a path q from y to z .

By Lemma 4.5,

$$P(t)=\begin{cases}
 p(2t)& \text{if, $0\le t\le 1/2$,}\\
 q(2t-1)&\text{if, $1/2\le t\le1$.}
  \end{cases}$$

The end points are P($0$)=x P(1)=z

P is continuous,since P
is restricted to closed subsets [0,0.5]
and [0.5,1] and [0,1]=[0,0.5] $\cup$ [0.5,1]

So we have a path from x to z(obviously
transitive)

Since X=p $\cup$ q and p $\cap$q=$\emptyset$

we have found z$\in P_x$

Any help would be appreciated in helping
prove it.

Comment: You need the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) for the case of two closed sets, **not** Thm 9.9 you quoted which is irrelevant for this.

Comment: Ok I believe I found a Lemma. that mentions it